# Convert 3 Hex (byte) to Decimal

Tags: c#, hex, byte, decimal

How do I take the hex `0A 25 10 A2` and get the end result of `851.00625`? This must be multiplied by `0.000005`. I have tried the following code without success:

```
 byte oct6 = 0x0A;
 byte oct7 = 0x25;
 byte oct8 = 0x10;
 byte oct9 = 0xA2;

 decimal BaseFrequency = Convert.ToDecimal((oct9 | (oct8 << 8) | (oct7 << 16) | (oct6 << 32))) * 0.000005M;
```

I am not getting `851.00625` as the BaseFrequency.

Comment: It's not clear *why* you would expect those bytes to give 851.00625. Do you have a description for this format anywhere?

Comment: Should that `<< 32` be `<<24` ?

Comment: Bingo John3136. If you put that in an answer I'll accept it.

Comment: Ah, so when you say "This" must be multiplied by 0.000005 you mean "Convert the bytes to a 32 bit integer and then multiply by..." Your question was unclear. Do you *actually* have those bytes in four separate variables, or do you have them in an array? If you've got an array, then BitConverter would be simpler.

Comment: Sorry Jon Skeet. I'm still learning so I wasn't able to specify what I meant any further. Thanks for saying what I meant so I can know for future reference what I need to explain to people.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`oct6` is being shifted 8 bits too far (32 instead of 24)

```
decimal BaseFrequency = Convert.ToDecimal((oct9 | (oct8 << 8) | (oct7 << 16) | (oct6 << 24))) * 0.000005M;
```